# How can I get the value of a variable without lose it value?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I know that maybe this is a silly question but I do not know what to do.
I want to pass a value to a function, the problem is that I lose the value that I want. I tried to do this in one function or in the other and the result is the same.
I want to do a function after another function ends, I know that I can do that with a callback, but how I have to pass a parameter, the callback function doesn´t work, or at least I do not know how to do that.

Mi controller

```
function Crud(){   
    $this->crud->set_table('test');
    (...)
    $output = $this->crud->render();
    $data['page_title'] = 'Test';
    $data = array_merge($data, (array) $output);

    $state_code = $this->crud->getState();
    $info = '';
    $operation_message = 'in the Table';
        if ($state_code == 'add') 
        {
            $info = 'Inserted';
        }

    echo $info; // this value give me **empty**, and I want that give me **Inserted**
    $this->Insert_t($operation_message, $info)

}
```

**Aditional Information**

I am doing a kind of **Traces**, I do not know if that is the English name. 
A function that **save** all that a user do if insert a record, I save the record in the correspondent table, and in another table, the action "the user Pepe insert a test". With the correspondent `DateTime`, `ip_address`

I do not know what I am doing wrong.
thank´s in advance.

Comment: Did you check to see what the value of $state_code is? If it isn't 'add' then an empty value is correct for $info

Comment: yes, sometime is add, some times doesn´t, that is the problem. I am doing a kind of **Traces**, i do not know if that is the english name. A function that save all what a user do, if insert a record, i save the record in the correspondent table, and in another table the action "the user **Pepe** insert a test"

Comment: how do you get that "$state_code" value?

Comment: `$state_code = $this->crud->getState();` I see that in a page and I tried

Answer (score 0):

You can echo $state_code value.If you are getting as "add " then you will surely get result as "inserted"